# Fitting a mixed model in r with grouped variance structures similar to SAS glimmix

Tags: sas, lme4, anova, random-effects

I am trying to fit a mixed model in r and get a variance grouped by a factor.

The initial model in SAS is:

```
proc glimmix data=Marsh.KISR_quad_mean (where=(eval=1)) plots=all ; *initial eval=0;
by eval;
class Site Plot Season Trt;
model Perc_HYAM= Site Season Site*Season 
                    Trt Season*Trt Site*Trt Site*Trt*Season    / ddfm=kr  ;
random Plot*Site ;
    random Plot*Site*Season ; 
lsmeans Site Season Site*season Trt Season*Trt site*trt site*trt*season  / cl ;
run;
```

The R version that works is:

```
Eval_Site_Fixed_NI_AOV <-function(dvar) paste(dvar,
                "~ SITE + (1|BLOCK:SITE) +",
                "SEASON + SITE:SEASON + (1|BLOCK:SITE:SEASON) +",
                "TRT + SITE:TRT + SEASON:TRT + SITE:SEASON:TRT", sep=" ")
lmer(Eval_Site_Fixed_NI_AOV("perc_HYAM"),
 data=KISR_Quad_means_E1)
```

The model with grouped variance in SAS is:

```
proc glimmix data=Marsh.KISR_quad_mean (where=(eval=1)) plots=all; *initial eval=0;
by eval;
class Site Plot Season Trt;
model Perc_HYAM= Site Season Site*Season 
                    Trt Season*Trt Site*Trt Site*Trt*Season    / ddfm=kr  ;
 random Plot*Site ;
    **random Plot*Site*Season /group=Trt ; **
lsmeans Site Season Site*season Trt Season*Trt site*trt site*trt*season  / ilink cl ;
run;
```

The random Plot*Site*Season is grouped by factor=Trt.  My attempt, which is clearly wrong, was to use:

```
Eval_Site_TGroup_AOV <-function(dvar) paste(dvar,
                "~ SITE + (1|BLOCK:SITE) +",
                "SEASON + SITE:SEASON + (TRT|BLOCK:SITE:SEASON) +",
                "TRT + SITE:TRT + SEASON:TRT + SITE:SEASON:TRT", sep=" ")
```

I have searched a few other packages that may allow specification of random effects but have not found a good example of how to equate what I do with SAS to r.

The random effects statement in r does not produce an separate estimate of variance for 2 treatment levels but a large matrix that exceeds the number of observations.